# How to use "lockunspent" in bitcoin core wallet console?

Tags: wallet, json-rpc

Try to use the Lockunspend RPC in bitcoin core wallet console. But always get wrong, and google it can't find answer.

My input is:

```
lockunspent false "[{"txid":"c3fa34606ae3ea416ff640d97414ef6a0a8afcebfbe2c60403ad60c0d961f04c","vout":0}]"
```

Is anyone can teach me where I am wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you should to escape the inner quotes:

```
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"c3fa34606ae3ea416ff640d97414ef6a0a8afcebfbe2c60403ad60c0d961f04c\",\"vout\":0}]"
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not work. If with bitcoin-cli, your format should be work. But my problem is how to use is with bitcoin core wallet console. It seems that don't need to escape the inner quotes for console.

Comment: It should work, have you tried?

Comment: 10:37:01
￼
lockunspent false "[{\"txid\":\"c3fa34606ae3ea416ff640d97414ef6a0a8afcebfbe2c60403ad60c0d961f04c\",\"vout\":0}]"


10:37:01
￼
Invalid parameter, expected unspent output (code -8)

Comment: @yrm23 It's clearly not unspent.

Answer (score -1):

Try double quoting

```
lockunspent false '[{"\"txid\"":"\"c3fa34606ae3ea416ff640d97414ef6a0a8afcebfbe2c60403ad60c0d961f04c\"","\"vout\"":"0"}]'
```

Comment: please explain why this is down voted